# Countably many isolated points implies that any disjoint union of open sets is countable.

Tags: general-topology

I have a problem in general topology that I am not able to solve.

Let $X$ be a topological space with denumerably infinite many isolated points. Then show that any collection of pairwise disjoint open sets is denumerably infinite.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the question about showing that a ***collection*** of open sets is countable (as in the body of your post) or is it about showing that the ***union*** is countable (as in the title)?

Comment: I don't think there is any condition on a topological space $X$ which implies that any collection of pairwise disjoint open sets is ***infinite***, much less ***denumerably infinite***. There seem to be multiple problems with the question as you have stated it in English. Could you post the assignment in the original French?

Comment: **Counterexample.** Let $X=(-\infty,0)\cup\mathbb N,$ topologized as a subspace of $\mathbb R.$ Then $X$ is a topological space with denumerably many isolated points, namely, the points $1,2,3,\dots.$ Yet $\{(-4,-3),(-2,-1)\}$ is a collection of pairwise disjoint open sets which fails to be denumerably infinite, as it has only two members.

Comment: $X$ can have an uncountable family of pair-wise disjoint open sets even if the set of isolated points of $X$ is empty or finite or countably infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, the claim is false.

Let $B$ be any uncountable collection of pairwise disjoint sets, each containing at least two points, and let $X$ be the union of the members of $B$.

Let $T$ be the set of all unions of any number of members of $B.\;\,$Then

- $T$ is a topology on $X$.

  There are no isolated points.

  There is an uncountable collection of pairwise disjoint open sets, namely, the members of $B$.

For a concrete example, let $X = \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$, and let $B = \{\{x,-x\} \mid x > 0\}$. Thus, the topology $T$ will be comprised of all subsets $U$ of $X$ such that whenever $x$ in $U,\;-x$ is also in $U$.

**Edit:**

The original version of the question specified *countably* many isolated points, so my counterexample qualifies, since it has no isolated points.

But in the OP's new edit, the requirement is now a countably infinite number of isolated points, not just countable.

But it's easy to satisfy this new requirement . . .

Just take any countably infinite set $S$, where $S$ is disjoint from $X$, and let $Y = X \cup S$.

Then define a topology on $Y$ by declaring a subset of $Y$ as open if it's the union of a (possibly empty) subset of $S$ with an open (possibly empty) subset of $X$, where "open" means open in the topology previously defined on $X$.

Then $Y$ is a topological space with a countably infinite number of isolated points, namely the points of $S$, and there is an uncountable collection of pairwise disjoint open subsets of $Y$, namely, the members of $B$.

Alternatively, here's a concrete example, similar to the old one, which satisfies the new requirements . . .

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$, and declare a set open if it's the union of a (possibly empty) subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ with a (possibly empty) subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}$ such that whenever $x$ is in $U,\;-x$ is also in $U$.

Then the set of isolated points of $X$ is the set $\mathbb{Z}$, which is countably infinite, and the set
$$B = \{\{x,-x\} \mid x\in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}\;\text{and}\;x > 0\}$$
is an uncountable collection of pairwise disjoint open subsets of $X$.

Comment: Thank you.  I've been sitting here trying to figure out what was wrong with my counterexample, and the answer is -- nothing.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think this is not the point of the exercise. To disprove the statement, you would need to show the existence of a topology X with 1. a collection B of uncountably (infinitely) many pairwise disjoint open sets 2. countably (infinitely) many isolated points.

Comment: Countable does not mean countably infinite. Finite sets are also countable. But it doesn't matter. For any space $X$, we can adjoin a countably infinite set, and declare all the new singletons as open.

Comment: The exercise is formulated in French and perhaps my translation of "dénombrable" into countable was not the most accurate. Sorry about that. I guess denumerable would be the right terminology in this case.